# Nginx proxy_pass to basex

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have BasexHttp running on port 8984 and Nginx is proxying it to port 80.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://212.71.232.36:8984/rest/;
        proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

If I navigate to http://212.71.232.36:8984/rest/hello/world I get the correct response (xml).

However, if I navigate to http://212.71.232.36/hello/world I get "Database not found".

Why is the proxy not working as expected?

Ubuntu 16.10
BaseX 8.6.1
Nginx 1.10.1
Openjdk 1.8.0_121

Comment: `hellow` !== `hello`. `212.71.232.36` !== `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I fixed this issue by changing the proxy url to proxy_pass http://212.71.232.36:8984;